# Trello permissions and privileges

Tags: trello, permissions

In my fire department, we use Trello between higher rank officers to track tasks around the fire house and it’s really effective.

However, we had an issue where someone in the organisation, who has normal privileges, was able to comment on a card they were not invited to attend. If a person is not a "member" on a card, but a member on the board, will they be able to see any card displayed?

Also, can you make only certain people have the ability to shift cards around?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all board members can see, comment on and change cards in the board.

If you only want specific people to access cards in a certain board then make the board private to only those members assigned rights to that board.